# Web Speech API recognition

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, распознавание-речи

```js
 var recognition = new (SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition)();
       recognition.lang = "ru-RU";
    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        if (event.results.length > 0) {
            q.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            q.form.submit();
        }
    }
```

```html
<form action="http://www.example.com/search">
    <input type="search" id="q" name="q" size=60>
    <input type="button" value="Click to Speak" onclick="recognition.start()">
</form>
```

Выдает ошибку:
*SpeechRecognition is not defined*

Подскажите: в чем проблема?

Comment: Может у кого есть готовый код, который преобразует речь в текст по нажатию кнопки?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что если `SpeechRecognition` не существует, то будет вызван `ReferenceError`, потому что интепретатор не знает, что это такое и думает, что это не определенная переменная.

Что бы это исправить, надо обратиться к `SpeechRecognition` как к свойству объекта `window`. В таком случае, если он не существует, то будет возвращено `undefined`.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/3zkv6929/).

Попробуйте вот это:

```js
var recognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition)();
       recognition.lang = "ru-RU";
    recognition.onresult = function (event) {
        if (event.results.length > 0) {
            q.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            q.form.submit();
        }
    }
```

```html
<form action="http://www.example.com/search">
    <input type="search" id="q" name="q" size=60>
    <input type="button" value="Click to Speak" onclick="recognition.start()">
</form>
```

Comment: странно, но вот хром не хочет видеть микрофон, не подскажите в чем дело?

Comment: Самое банальное - а микрофон работает? Кстати, возможно также что микрофон заблокирован. В других браузерах работает?

Comment: самое интересное то, что стоит 5 браузеров, захожу на любую страницу с примером и все работает, копирую к себе код, запускаю и отказывается что-либо выполнять...

Comment: @Deepsleep я добавил примера на jsfiddle, посмотрите, работает ли у вас там...